# Send an email response when a Google form is filled during specific working hours

Tags: google-apps-script

We have requests / tickets coming across teams which are in different countries. And these requests are submitted through Google Forms. These requests / tickets are then picked at a single location and processed

There's a 5 hour non working window from 00:00 am to 5am. During this time as well we do get requests from the offices.

Is there a way if a form is submitted during this non workings hours an email notification goes to the requester letting them know that we are closed and the request submitted will be picked once we are open?

There is an option to run script. But i get an error.

If a script has to be run, how would that be possible based on the requirement?

Thanks

Comment: Here's the script i had created :
function sendEmail(e) {
//response
//getRespondentEmail()
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email.html");
var htmlText = html.evaluate().getContent();
//logger.log(htmlText);
var emailTo = e.response.getRespondentEmail();
var subject = "Thanks for filling the form";
var textBody = "This email requires HTML support make sure you opn";
var options ={ htmlBody: htmlText };
if (emailTo !== undefined){
GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, textBody, options);}}

Comment: But got the following error :
TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined`enter code here`
sendEmail @ Code.gs:8`enter code here`

Comment: Posting your script in your question makes it much more readable and it's more likely we will read it.  As for myself I have not read it and I'm not going to unless you post it nicely into your question. [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will encounter such error when you tried to run your code manually using the Script Editor because your event object doesn't exist.

I tried to run your code using an on-form submit in Google Form itself and it was triggered successfully when I submit a form as an example. [Google Forms events - Form submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1)

**Using on-form submit installable trigger in Google Forms:**

[image]

### Sample Code:

```
function sendEmail(e) { 
  //response //getRespondentEmail() 
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email.html"); 
  var htmlText = html.evaluate().getContent(); 
  //logger.log(htmlText); 
  var emailTo = e.response.getRespondentEmail(); 
  var subject = "Thanks for filling the form"; 
  var textBody = "This email requires HTML support make sure you opn"; 
  var options ={ htmlBody: htmlText }; 

  var today = new Date();
  Logger.log(today.getHours())
  if (emailTo !== undefined && today.getHours() < 5){ 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, textBody, options);
  }
}
```

**Modifications done:**

- I just include an additional condition to check for the current time when the form was submitted to check if it is within 00:00 to 05:00. Refer to [JavaScript getHours() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gethours.asp)
- In this sample code, the email will only be sent when a form was submitted from 00:00 to 04:59. You can adjust the condition based on your preference if you want. You can also include checking the minutes using [JavaScript getMinutes() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getminutes.asp)

**Note:**

- You can debug your installable triggers by adding logs in your code and by checking the `Executions` tab in the Apps Script Editor.

Comment: Thanks this is working now and resolved. We are now getting the automated responses. But just a question, how do I change the from email to? When the automated email is sent to the requestor. Can we have an DL email ID instead of the person who created or saving the script?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: How can the from email ID be changed to a DL mail Box ID. Rather than a persons email ID (Example : if i want to show that the email notification has come from this ID Ticket@mm.com.

Comment: You can add `from` parameter in your send email [advance parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#advanced-parameters_1). But you need to configure your email id  `Ticket@mm.com` as an [email alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en) for your email. You can check if your email alias was successfully setup when you use [GmailApp.getAliases()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getaliases)

Comment: If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: I have just tried to run this script by adding the alias parameter. But it does seem to trigger

Comment: function sendEmail(e) { 
 //response //getRespondentEmail() 
 var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email.html"); 
 var htmlText = html.evaluate().getContent(); 
 //logger.log(htmlText); 
 var emailTo = e.response.getRespondentEmail(); 
 var form = GmailApp.getAliases()
 var subject = "Thanks for filling the form"; 
 var textBody = ""; 
 var options ={ htmlBody: htmlText }; 
 var today = new Date();
 Logger.log(today.getHours())
 if (emailTo !== undefined && today.getHours() < 5){ 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, textBody, options,{from: 'your_alias'});
  }}

Comment: If you are able to successfully create an [email alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en). This array should not be empty. `var form = GmailApp.getAliases()`. Then it should be `var options ={ htmlBody: htmlText, from: form[0] };`. Something like this

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onFormSubmit trigger for spreadsheets.  It provides all of the information for each submission via namedValues which is an object or values which is an array. As an installable trigger it is capable of performing operations that require permission like sending emails.

[onFormSubmit event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

There are many examples of doing this on this site.